# Where are notes stored on Xiaomi Pocophone F1? (kind of an emergency)

Tags: notes

I have managed to transfer my old phone's storage (Xiaomi Pocophone F1) to my PC right before its screen died (the whole directory) and I have recently bought a Xiaomi Pocophone X3. I have managed to transfer some files from the PC to it (and it worked) and I want to transfer the notes of the older phone to the new phone.
Does anyone know where are the notes stored on the Xiaomi Pocophone F1? It would really help me guys.
Package name of the notes app: com.miui.notes.Application

Comment: When talking about specific apps like "Notes" please provide it's package package name or the link to Google Play so that we know about what app you are talking about. Because there are dozens of apps with the name "Notes" available.

Comment: hi sorry for not being specific i dont know much about this topic... it is the notes app which came with the phone system it's not on Google Play. how could I find the specifications you need?

Comment: check [micloud](https://i.mi.com/?_locale=en)

Comment: i was too stupid to back it up... IMO my notes exist only on my computer and on my old phone. The problem is that my old phone can't be used and that I don't know where the notes are stored on my computer.

Comment: Then most likely you are talking about [this app](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/xiaomi-inc/miui-notes/). Package name of the app should be `com.miui.notes.Application`.

Comment: thanks I'll add it to the post

Comment: Then most likely the data is stored in `/data/data/com.miui.notes.Application` – but you cannot access that except using root powers. With some luck it was using "external storage" and thus had them on the SD card (aka "shared storage") in `Android/data/com.miui.notes.Application` which you can access.

Comment: alecxs, could you simplify what you commented i dont know much about this topic...

Comment: izzy, the folder Android/data/com.miui.notes.Application does exist but it's empty

Comment: simplified: if your poco f1 still exist you can mirror the screen to pc via usb cable and read your notes

Comment: akecxs it does exist but its screen is dead will it still work?

Comment: i mean i cant allow usb debugging because my screen is done plus i cant open my phone since it requires a password (i know it but i cant type it)

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work without touchscreen :( It should be possible to connect bluetooth keyboard, but with physical keyboard it's impossible. You can however try to tap blind (hopefully touch input is still working) https://www.mediafire.com/file/aiu6pz6qhfvy0ap

Comment: alecxs, i guess i will have to live on without these notes, they were important to me but not crucial. i guess i will sometime get the screen fixed and look through the old notes. anyway, thank you for the help i appreciate it.